# What kind of data structure is it in the following code, and how would you reference the first element?

Tags: perl

What kind of data structure is being created in the following code snippet, and how would you reference the first element?

```
my $value= { 1 => "Apple", 2 => "Orange", 3 => "Banana" };
```

Why do we use `=>`, can you explain?

According to me the above code is invalid and instead it should be my `%value` then it becomes hash.

Comment: It's been a while, but doesn't that get you a *reference* to the hash? As in, dereference using `%$value`?

Comment: Could get you can you elloborate

Comment: "According to me the above code is invalid...." Well, you're wrong. It's a hash because it has curly brackets and key-value pairs. If you put `%value` on the left-hand side it would be wrong. You would store `undef` in the slot for the key which is the stringified representation of the anonymous hashref -> `$value{'HASH(0xABCDEF999)'} = undef`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It a hash reference. See [perldoc perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html).

There isn't a "first" element because hashes don't have an fixed order. You'd access the value of `1` by using `$value->{"1"}`.

You use the [fat comma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_comma) (`=>`) because:

- It puts quotes around the LHS automatically
- It gives a strong visual indicator as to which bits of the data are keys and which are values

A hash reference is a scalar value, so you need `$`. `%value` would be used if you were storing a hash directly, but then you'd use `()` instead of `{}`.

Comment: HI @quentin                                                    
             when i am trying to print the below it return me with an error 
                print "$value{'1'}\n";

Comment: @iamnewbie — Of course it does. That isn't how I said you accessed the value.

Comment: Try using this $value -> {'1'} and check whether it works or not ?

Comment: Check my o/p below    
`#!/usr/bin/perl
my $value = { 1 => "Apple", 2 => "Orange", 3 => "Banana" };
print $value->{"1"};

root@ubuntu-OptiPlex-390:~/sammy/new# ./q1.pl
Apple
root@ubuntu-OptiPlex-390:~/sammy/new#
`

Comment: @praveen
Can you please also tell me whats the difference in below 2 declaration 

my $thing1 = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
my @ thing2 = ( 1, 2, 3 );

Comment: Pretty much the same thing.

Comment: but technically whats the difference according to me @ points to address and $ points to the value ?

Comment: `$` is a scalar. `@` is an array.

Comment: @iamnewbie, Always use `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: @ikegami is it correct to say that hash elements order doesn't change until hash itself isn't changed (hint: `values()` always returns corresponding values)?

Comment: @Quentin yes, but order should change only when hash is altered.

Comment: @Сухой27, Yes. Subsequent iterations of the hash (keys/values/each) will return the same order as previous iterations of a hash if the hash hasn't been changed in between. e.g. `@b{keys(%a)} = values(%a);` is a fine way to add the elements of one hash to another. That's documented.

Comment: @ikegami — I must have missed that. Where in the docs is that?

Comment: @ikegami
    #What is the difference between below 2 line
    my @ ary = ( 1, 2, 3 );       # variable
    print "size = " . @ ary . "\n";      #first statement      
    print "size = @ ary \n";             #Second statement  
    # tell me the difference between above two statements

Comment: @iamnewbie — If you have a new question, then please [ask it in the right place](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: the thing is when i try to post my code there it ask me to put comments for your code when i put comments for my code it still says add more comments to help understand your code,, i am new with this web and really sad with the way its structured .. :(

Comment: No, it doesn't say anything about commenting your code. It says this this box is to be used to leave comments about the answer. You are using it to ask new questions. Ask questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)